# Pandas apply to unknown column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following Dataframe:

```
position     a_0     a_1     a_2     a_3     a_4     new_value
2             10     13                                100
3             12     16       13                       120
2             14     12                                140
4             15     11       16      16               150
```

I would like to create the following:

```
position     a_0     a_1     a_2     a_3     a_4     new_value
2             10     13      100                       100
3             12     16       13     120               120
2             14     12      140                       140
4             15     11       16      16     150       150
```

Essentially, set each row at index `position` to be equal to `new_value`.
Ideally without using a for loop.

The difficulty is referring to a different column to set a value for each row. The only idea I've had is to break up the original dataframe into smaller dataframes (based on the value of `position`) and then just use the `apply` function.

Any other ideas would be super helpful!

Thanks

Comment: Please add your data as text, not images.

Comment: not sure how with keeping the tabular format?

Comment: Yes it can at least in your case, do `print(df)` and copy/paste. You can also do `print(df.to_dict())`...

Comment: This isn't the real data. It's a mock example. Unable to share the data. I hope that's still fine?

Comment: SO is generally [against image data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Specially for [Pandas related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). You don't need to share your real data. What you have there should be good, even in csv form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you data it is unclear that the blank cells are `np.nan` or empty string `''`, also what data types are. A `print(df.to_dict())` could have been better. That said, let's assume that those are empty strings `''`:

```
# only work on interested column
s = df.loc[:,'a_0':'a_4']

# use `s.isna()` if they are `None` or `NaN`
df.loc[:, 'a_0':'a_4'] = np.where(s.eq('').cumsum(1).eq(1), 
                                  df['new_val'].values[:,None],s)
```

Output:

```
   position  a_0  a_1    a_2  a_3  a_4  new_val
0         2   10   13  100.0                100
1         3   12   16   13.0  120           120
2         2   14   12  140.0                140
3         4   15   11   16.0   16  150      150
```

Comment: amazing, could you perhaps explain the mechanics of what's happening in the code? specifically in the np.where statement

Comment: `s.eq('').cumsum(1).eq(1)` mask the first `NaN` occurs in a row, print it out to see details. `np.where` check the conditions, if `True`, choose the first one, else second.